# Use knockout to load page based on some condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, single-page-application

I have a SPA web application with tabular content. Each tab content should load based on what user choose from menu. For example if a user clicked customer list, tab should be add to its container and content should be a list of customer view. I want to know how should I bind a content to a page and/or a partial view.

**Update**

Here is my tab mark-up

```
<div class="tabbable span9" data-bind="with: tabs, visible: tabs().length > 0">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-bind="foreach: $data">
    <li data-bind="css: { active: isActive() > 0 }">
        <a data-toggle="tab" data-bind="text: title(), attr: { href: tabUrl() } "></a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" data-bind="foreach: $data">
    <div class="tab-pane" data-bind="attr: { id: uid(), }, css: { active: isActive() > 0 }">
        <p data-bind="text: title()"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my view model :

```
// add tab to tab container
self.addTab = function (id, type, title, isActive) {
    self.tabs.push(new uitab(id, type, title, isActive));
};
```

And finally this is my tab model :

```
function uitab(id, type, title, isactive) {
    var self = this;
    self.tabType = ko.observable(type);
    self.id = ko.observable(id);
    self.title = ko.observable(title);
    self.isActive = ko.observable(isactive);
    self.uid = ko.observable(token());
    self.tabUrl = ko.computed(function () {
        return '#'+self.uid();
    });
}
```

Comment: Gonna have to show some code of what you have tried or what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this kind of situations is using [template-binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html).